# How to create table tennis database model in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

- Create   new users
- Create new   tournaments
  (Each tournament will be in the round-robin style where each player
  must play all other players twice)
- Register users to tournaments
- Create a game (winner is first to score  21) between two users within
  a tournament
- Update   the score   of  an  ongoing game
- See  a   ranking of  users   within  a   tournament by   games   won

  Complete a tournament
- Give points  to  players based on their position in the tournament
- Give points  to players for other subjective awards, such as best
  serve,   or best smash
- See  a ranking of users based on the number of points won
  across   all tournaments

how can design database scheme for this type of data ?

Comment: Share your attempts ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer transactional data, rather than updating. This gives a full history of what's happened.

```
create table player (id int not null, 
                     firstname varchar(30),
                     lastname varchar(30),
                     joinndate date);

create table tournament (id int not null,
                         rundate date);

create table player_tournament (tournament_id int, --fk to tournament.id
                                player_id, -- fk to player.id
                                registerdate date);
```

So now we record each game, and the frames that make it. The frames are the individual points,and recording each one allows more options on reporting.

```
create table game (id int not null,
                   player_id int, -- fk to player.id
                   player_pos int, -- 1 or 2
                   tournament_id int); -- fk to tournament.id

create table frame (id int not null,
                    game_id int, -- fk to game.id
                    frame_number int,
                    win_player_pos int); -- refers to the game.player_pos
```

Score of game:

```
select g1.id, 
       sum(case when win_player_pos = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Player1,
       sum(case when win_player_pos = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Player2
from game g1
inner join frame
on game_id = g1.id
```